# Using grepl for extracting characters of both numbers and letters

Tags: r, grepl

I have a dataset were each person has one line with a specific id number and a factor consisting of both letters and numbers representing different diagnose codes. Now I want to create a dichotomous variable based on whether an id has the diagnose code or not using ifelse

```
    diag<-c("G45", "C25", "1700", "1710", "1800", "G46")
    id<-c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6")
    data<-data.frame(diag, id)
    data$disease1<- ifelse(grepl("^1700-^1710|G45", data$diag), 1, 0)

    table(data$disease1)
    > table(data$disease1)

    0 1 
    5 1
```

The result of the table function shows 1 for the G45.

How to extract both the factors containing the digits only and the blended digits and letters?

Comment: `grepl("\\w{0,1}\\d+", as.character(d$c_dod1))`?

Comment: Please try and make this example more reproducible. Perhaps just provide a sample vector containing a few diagnosis codes -- some which would be tagged `1` and other cases that would be tagged `0`.

Comment: diag<-c("G45", "C25", "1700", "1710", "1800", "G46")
id<-c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6")
data<-data.frame(diag, id)
data$disease1<- ifelse(grepl("^1700-^1710", data$diag), 1, 0)
table(data$disease1)

the results in the table show

> table(data$disease1)

0 
6

Comment: @Daniel can you please edit the question and add the data to it? Also, please indicate what your expected output should look like.

Comment: sure! data provided now

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? `data$disease1<- ifelse(grepl("\\w{0,1}\\d+", as.character(data$diag)), 1, 0)` and `table(data$disease1)`.

Comment: @Abdou thanks, it gives me some output but i do not understand the process?

Comment: 1. Is the output what you expected? 2. The process uses what is known as [`regular expression`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). The expression `"\\w{0,1}\\d+"` looks for a factor that starts with zero or one alphanumeric (letters or numbers) character (that's what `\\w{0,1}` is), followed by 1 or more digits (that's what `\\d+` is). Take a look at regular expressions. They are very powerful for character filtering.

Comment: But how to extract a specific character such as 1700?

Comment: If you want ***one*** specific character like 1700, then you may have to replace the entire regular expression with just that character: so `grepl("1700", as.character(data$diag))`.

Comment: Meaning no additional expressions can be made in the same string such as also filtering "G45"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116848/discussion-between-abdou-and-daniel).